# Using Flextable in a Function in R

Tags: r, function, flextable

I am trying to create a function in R markdown for conditional formatting while using flextable package.
I am trying to color format rows based on the condition which compares two columns.

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
cndnl_form <- function(data,mv1,ov1)

{
ft <- flextable({{data}})

ft <- color(ft, i = ~ ({{mv1}}- {{ov1}}/ abs({{mv1}}) > 0.25),
j = {{ov1}},
color="blue")

}

cndnl_form(df,"ft$3","ft$10")
```

but i am getting an error
Error during wrapup: object 'mv1' not found

Any idea, what should i change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether tidy eval will work in this context.

However, as `flextable` allows for formula specifications you can set up the condition as a formula for which I use `reformulate`.

Using `mtcars` as example data with the simple condition `mv1 > 20` try this:

```
library(flextable)

cndnl_form <- function(data, mv1, ov1) {
  ft <- flextable(data)

  row <- reformulate(paste(mv1, "> 20"))
  col <- reformulate(ov1)

  color(ft, i = row, j = col, color = "blue")
}

ft <- cndnl_form(head(mtcars), "mpg", "gear")
```

[image]